# Entity Framework customizing Foreign Key relationships

Tags: entity-framework, code-first, fluent

I am using Entity Framework 6. I have created my data models Code First and the database is up and running, everything is working just fine. Below is a pseudo representation of my data. I'll continue the explanation below the code snippet.

```
public class ObjectTypeA
{
    public ObjectTypeA()
    {
        Bs = new HashSet<ObjectTypeB>()
        Cs = new HashSet<ObjectTypeC>()
    }

    public ICollection<ObjectTypeB> Bs { get; private set;}
    public ICollection<ObjectTypeC> Cs { get; private set;}
}

public class ObjectTypeB
{
    [ForeignKey("ObjectA")]
    public Guid ObjectTypeAId { get; set; }

    public virtual ObjectTypeA ObjectA { get; set;}
}

public class ObjectTypeC
{
    [ForeignKey("ObjectA")]
    public Guid ObjectTypeAId { get; set; }

    public virtual ObjectTypeA ObjectA { get; set;}
}
```

So, as I mentioned, everything is working fine, including cascade delete, which  is on by default. What I would like to be able to do is this:

Delete ObjectTypeA is allowed if there are ObjectTypeBs holding a key to it, but not if there are ObjectTypeCs holding keys to it.

If Cs.Count > 0, ObjectTypeA cannot be deleted.

Can this be done in the markup, does it need to be done in Fluent?
Since cascade delete is on, would a different approach be better where I turn it off and then enable it as an when desired? If so, how?

I looked at using nullable ForeignKeys but that doesn't appear to be the functionality I am looking for.

Comment: I dont think this can be done at all with the model in EF you would need to write a repository or some kind of wrapper to do this manually

Comment: Do you mean I will have to write some Fluent to run in the OnModelCreating, or just have my application do the checking before allowing the Delete proceed? If it's the 2nd option, then that would mean the DB itself doesn't know these rules and so would just delete everything as per normal.